# Failed to get D-Bus connection: unknown error -1

Tags: debian, systemd, raspberry-pi

Running OSMC on my Raspberry Pi 2b.
I set up a samba share a few days ago, there is nothing else I've done for the last few weeks with the Pi besides running a few daemons. It's running 24/7.

Now whenever I want to run a systemctl command, it says

```
Failed to get D-Bus connection: unknown error -1
```

Dbus is running in the process list:

```
427 ?        Ss     0:00 /usr/bin/dbus-daemon --system --address=systemd: --nofork --nopidfile --systemd-activation
```

I have no idea what's causing the issue, nothing else is running in the background. I am unable to connect to the Pi via SSH if its running for a few hours, I guess it has something to do with that error.

Comment: What happens if you run `systemctl status` as root?

Comment: Duplicates https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/381086/ .

Comment: That link to the alleged duplicate is broken.